# Python subprocess call rsync

Tags: python, rsync

I am trying to to run rsync for each folder in a folder.

```
__author__ = 'Alexander'
import os
import subprocess

root ='/data/shares'
arguments=["--verbose", "--recursive", "--dry-run", "--human-readable", "--remove-source-files"]
remote_host = 'TL-AS203'

for folder in os.listdir(root):
    print 'Sync Team ' + folder.__str__()

    path = os.path.join(root,folder, 'in')
    if os.path.exists(path):
        folder_arguments = list(arguments)
        print (type(folder_arguments))
        folder_arguments.append("--log-file=" + path +"/rsync.log")
        folder_arguments.append(path)
        folder_arguments.append("transfer@"+remote_host+":/data/shares/"+ folder+"/out")
        print "running rsync with " + str(folder_arguments)
        returncode = subprocess.call(["rsync",str(folder_arguments)])
        if returncode == 0:
            print "pull successfull"
        else:
            print "error during rsync pull"
    else:
        print "not a valid team folder, in not found"
```

If I run this I get the following output:

```
Sync Team IT-Systemberatung
<type 'list'>
running rsync with ['--verbose', '--recursive', '--dry-run', '--human-readable', '--remove-source-files', '--log-file=/data/shares/IT-Systemberatung/in/rsync.log', '/data/shares/IT-Systemberatung/in', 'transfer@TL-AS203:/data/shares/IT-Systemberatung/out']
rsync: change_dir "/data/shares/IT-Systemberatung/['--verbose', '--recursive', '--dry-run', '--human-readable', '--remove-source-files', '--log-file=/data/shares/IT-Systemberatung/in/rsync.log', '/data/shares/IT-Systemberatung/in', 'transfer@TL-AS203:/data/shares/IT-Systemberatung" failed: No such file or directory (2)
rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1040) [sender=3.0.4]
error during rsync pull
Sync Team IT-Applikationsbetrieb
not a valid team folder, in not found
transfer@INT-AS238:/data/shares/IT-Systemberatung
```

If i manually start rsync from bash with these arguments, everything works fine. I also tried it with shell=true but with the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do:

```
returncode = subprocess.call(["rsync"] + folder_arguments)
```

Calling `str()` on a list will return the string represention of the python list which is not what you want to pass in as an argument to `rsync`

Comment: Thanks, that solved my problem! what I dont unterstand why I need to use ((["rsync"] + folder_arguments) instead (["rsync"] , folder_arguments) ?

Comment: `subprocess.call` expects a single list for the full command line. The `+` operator merges two lists into a single list. Since folder_arguments is already a list, simply append it to a list containing only "rsync". So the resulting list would look like: ["rsync", "--verbose", "--recursive",...]

Answer (score 0):

You do a `os.chdir(os.path.join(root,folder))`, but never go back.

In order to properly resume operation on the next folder, you should either remember the last `os.getpwd()` and return to it, or just do `os.chdir('..')` at the end of one loop run.

Comment: Sorry, was a leftover in the code, dont use os.chdir anymore